# calculate date difference between two dates in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a input table format like.

```
ID1    ID2       date
1002    9648    2011-01-02
1003    9648    2011-06-06
1004    9648    2012-08-08
1005    9648    2016-01-06
1006    9648    2016-09-12
1007    9648    2018-01-22
1009    9744    2009-10-03
1010    9744    2012-01-10
1011    9744    2016-09-23
1012    9744    2017-10-25
1013    9923    2006-10-10
1014    10124   2017-10-11
1015    10124   2018-01-24
```

am looking for an output table as shown below.
Could you please help me with a sql query or how it can be achieved in talend.

if no of days between two dates exceed 1096 which is approximately 3 years I want to take it as zero and  update the type to new.

```
ID1      ID2    date    daysdifference  type
1002    9648    2011-01-02  0           new
1003    9648    2011-06-06  156         old
1004    9648    2012-08-08  429         old
1005    9648    2016-01-06  0           new
1006    9648    2016-09-12  250         old
1007    9648    2018-01-22  497         old
1009    9744    2009-10-03  0           new
1010    9744    2012-01-10  829         old
1011    9744    2016-09-23  0           new
1012    9744    2017-10-25  397         old
1013    9923    2006-10-10  0           new
1014    10124   2017-10-11  0           new
1015    10124   2018-01-24  91          old
```

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy.

Comment: Your output _almost_ looks like you want the date difference from the earliest date in each year to the current record for that year (and `ID2` value).  But the `2018-01-22` record makes no sense to me.  You should really tell us what is going on here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes for that date I took a date difference from 2016-09-12 date as both the ID2 values are same. where there is a new ID2 value the oldest date will be taken as new and moving forward it is updated as old and when time difference is greater than 1096 then I will make it to zero and update the type.

Comment: @ankushreddy I wrote that exact query, and it doesn't generate the output you want.  It is not clear how you are defining your windows with regard to the date difference.  Please tell us your logic (this is the reason you are drawing so many down votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**LAG**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to get the desired result you want. Basically, `LAG` function access the data of the previous row. From there, you can now calculate the difference between the previous date and the current date using `DATEDIFF` function. However, this function exist starting version 2012.

```
SELECT  ID1, ID2, Date, 
        DaysDifference = CASE WHEN PreviousDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
                CASE WHEN Date_Diff < 1096 THEN Date_Diff ELSE 0 END END,
        CASE WHEN PreviousDate IS NULL THEN 'NEW' ELSE 
                CASE WHEN Date_Diff < 1096 THEN 'OLD' ELSE 'NEW' END END
FROM 
        (
            SELECT  *,
                    LAG(date, 1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1) AS PreviousDate ,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(date, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1), date) Date_Diff
            FROM    TableA
        ) a
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58a2a/1).

However, if you are using version below 2012, you can still have the result you want using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH rows  AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1)
    FROM    TableA
)
SELECT  ID1, ID2, Date, 
        DaysDifference = CASE WHEN PreviousDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
                CASE WHEN Date_Diff < 1096 THEN Date_Diff ELSE 0 END END,
        CASE WHEN PreviousDate IS NULL THEN 'NEW' ELSE 
                CASE WHEN Date_Diff < 1096 THEN 'OLD' ELSE 'NEW' END END

FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.ID1, a.ID2, a.Date, b.Date as PreviousDate,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, b.date, a.date) Date_Diff
            FROM    rows a
                    LEFT JOIN rows b
                        ON a.RN = b.RN + 1
                            AND a.ID2 = b.ID2
        ) a
ORDER BY ID1, ID2
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68605/1).

Comment: This seems to generate the expected output, but you should explain your logic, because it is totally unclear from the original question +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select [id1], [id2], [date],
   case when [daysdifference] > 1096 then 0 else [daysdifference] end [daysdifference],
   case when [daysdifference] > 1096 then 'new' else 'old' end [type]
from (
   select *, abs(isnull(datediff(day, LAG([date], 1) over (order by id2, id1), 
[date]), 0)) [daysdifference] from @x
) [a]
```